# How do i set my android app to have priority on a bluetooth device

Tags: bluetooth, android-bluetooth, android

I created an android application and I want to give to it priority for the Bluetooth, when i open the app I want to log in first to a Bluetooth device and not another application similar to mine. So if someone knows how i get my application the priority (or how can i do it a default application concerning the specific Bluetooth device) over an other similar application.

Comment: Is this your problem: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" /> ?

Comment: no just an other app is connected before my app on the bt device and i dono why..

Comment: So you want your app to connect to a device before another app connects? What would your desired output for the other app be, blocked or just run after yours?

Comment: just run after mine or what ever,  i just want to connect first on the Bt device.

Comment: I think that is impossible if the other app is not started by your app. Your app cannot control all other apps, telling them when, where and how to run. This would lead to a huge security risk. However, if you call an app, you can choose *when* to call it and you would have (some) control.